# Script for Sharing folders to specific users

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I was wondering if there was an option to share and edit options using a script instead of going one by one.

So here's what I have to do: 
I have folder ABC and inside there's folders 1, 2, 3, 4, and so on, each with the name of the user that is 1, 2, 3 and 4.

The folder ABC is shared to everyone, but my users can only see their own folder, eg.: **User 1 can only see folder 1.
The only exceptions being admin/owners of course.**

It's just that I don't want to do it by hand for 200 people -.- 
*An automated script would help. Thanks ^^*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that with PnP SPOnline.

Here is a good example how to do this
https://collab365.community/using-powershell-pnp-create-permission-multiple-folders-office-365/

```
#1
$siteurl = "https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename"                
#2
$listname = "Library/list name"          
#3
$access = "full control" 
#4
$Folders = Import-Csv "link to your CSV file"    


 #----------START OF SCRIPT DO NOT MODIFY----------#
 connect-PnPOnline –Url $siteurl –Credentials (Get-Credential)
 foreach ( $entry in $Folders )
 {

$foldername = $entry.name
$emailaddress = $entry.EmailAddress


#Create Folder
Add-PnPFolder -Name $foldername -Folder $listname 

#get folder properites from list
$listItem = Get-PnPListItem -List $listname -Query "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>$foldername</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"

Write-Host "setting folder up for $foldername"

#set permissions on the folder
Set-PnPListItemPermission -List $listname -Identity $listItem -User $emailaddress -AddRole $access -ClearExisting

}

 #----------END OF SCRIPT DO NOT MODIFY----------#
```

Comment: I had to change the $access value because for some reason it only accepts the language that the page is in, which is not English. Besides that it works like a charm. Thanks ^^